# Vertex shader to rotate a ThreeJS object

Tags: three.js, shader, vertex-shader

I'd like to rotate a mesh round the y axis, and I use this code to generate the mesh:

```
const coinMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: { 
        rotationMatrix: { type: 'mat4', value: SHADERS.COIN_ROTATION_MATRIX }
    },
    wireframe: false,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    vertexShader: SHADERS.coinRotationShader(), 
    fragmentShader: SHADERS.coinFragmentShader()
});
const coinGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(5, 2, 8, 30);
const coinMesh = new THREE.Mesh(coinGeometry, coinMaterial);
```

And here you can see the SHADERS module, which generates the rotation matrix, and the shaders:

```
export function coinRotationShader() { //vertex shader 
    return "                                \
    uniform mat4 rotationMatrix;            \
    void main() {                           \
        vec4 rotatedPosition = rotationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0); \
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * rotatedPosition; \
    } \
    ";
}

export function coinFragmentShader() { //just applies yellow color
    return "                        \
    void main() {                   \
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0, 1.0);   \
    }                               \
    ";
}

const ROTATION_ANGLE = (2*Math.PI) / 60.0; //angle of rotation

export const COIN_ROTATION_MATRIX = createCoinRotationMatrix();

function createCoinRotationMatrix() { //rotates around Y axis
    const rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    rotationMatrix.makeRotationY(ROTATION_ANGLE);
    return rotationMatrix;
}
```

The object, however is **not rotating**. It appears at the correct position, and it's yellow, so the fragment shader is working. Am I constructing the matrix wrong, or misusing it in the vertex shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are not setting up `rotationMatrix` correctly. Keep in mind that the parameter of `Matrix4.makeRotationY()` is defined in radians (not degrees). Try it with the following code as a basis. The plane is rotated by 45 degrees around the y axis.

```js
function coinRotationShader() { //vertex shader 
    return `                                
    uniform mat4 rotationMatrix;            
    void main() {                           
        vec4 rotatedPosition = rotationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * rotatedPosition;
    }
    `;
}

function coinFragmentShader() { //just applies yellow color
    return `
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0, 1.0);
    }
    `;
}

function createCoinRotationMatrix() { //rotates around Y axis
    const rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    rotationMatrix.makeRotationY( Math.PI * 0.25 );
    return rotationMatrix;
}

//

let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 5;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const coinMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: { 
            rotationMatrix: { value: createCoinRotationMatrix() }
        },
        vertexShader: coinRotationShader(), 
        fragmentShader: coinFragmentShader()
    });
    const coinGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
    const coinMesh = new THREE.Mesh(coinGeometry, coinMaterial);
    
    scene.add( coinMesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.js"></script>
```

Notice that you can achieve the same result by just modulating `Object3D.rotation`.

Comment: So I was just using too small of an angle to see the difference. Anyways, I was under the impression that this would continously rotate my object, like an animation (thats why I used the small angle, to make it smooth). But it seems to do that I need to keep updating the rotation matrix as time goes by. I'll try implementing that.

Comment: @Gtomika The rotation matrix will only take the vertex from it's original position into the position defined by the rotation matrix. So, yes, you must either pass in a new rotation matrix each time, or at least define a new `uniform` to define a multiplier (which you would continuously update) which you use with the matrix to compute the total rotation.

Comment: @Mugen87 I have a quick follow up question, but dont want to clutter the original. Can you please take a look? https://pastebin.com/ENhpuhni

Comment: Not sure why this happens. Probably better to ask a new question and sharing a live example. Or consider to create a topic at the [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/). Posting there is less restrictive than at stackoverflow.